# SignalR callback not getting executed even if it receives trigger from backEnd. How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, angular, signalr, adal

I'm invoking a signalR connecting and listen to the callBack method. The console log shows that the callback method has been triggered, but the code inside the callback method is not getting executed.

The console log is printed as below:

SignalRConnection.proxy.on invoked. Calling listener next() ...

listener next() called.

The code snippet:

```
c.invoke('ABC', value, apiToken).then(() => {
        console.log('ABC Connected');
});
```

//call back method.

```
c.listenForRaw('receiveABCNotification')
        .subscribe((data: any[]) => {
          console.log('Data received from SIGNALr', data);
});
```

What should I do to make sure the code inside the listener method(callBack method) gets executed?

Comment: Show me your code

Comment: any update ? did you solve it ?